# Cross Product of Two List<String>

Tags: apex, developer-console

I want to do a concatenation of two List of string. in one I have ad example 'a' ,'b', 'c' and in one other I have a symbol like this '*'.

**Input**

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] x ['*', '°']
```

**Output**

```
[a*, b*, c*, a°, b°, c°]
```

**Preliminary Attempt**

```
List <String> list = new List<String>{'a','b','c'};
List<String> symbol = new List<String>{'*', '°'};
List<String> result= new List<String>();
for(String s : list){

    result= list + symbol;           
    }
```

How I can do it?

Comment: what do you mean by concatenate?

Comment: Did you want to concatenate the lists or the strings in the lists?

Comment: Are you looking for a result of `[a, b, c,* , °]`, or the cross-product/cartesian product `[a*, b*, c*, a°, b°, c°]`?

Comment: the cross-product/ cartesian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through both `List<String>`. I also recommend you don't ever name a variable `list`.

More like:

```
List<String> items = new List<String> { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
List<String> symbols = new List<String>{'*', '°'};
List<String> combos = new List<String>();
for (String item : items)
{
    for (String symbol : symbols)
    {
        combos.add(item + symbol);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a list of every possible concatenation of elements in `list` and `symbol` - let me know if I've misinterpreted what you are trying to do.

Since `Lists` are iterative types, you need to iterate over each member of your first list and concatenate it with each member of your second list.  So, try this:

```
List <String> letters = new List<String>{'a','b','c'}; //I've changed this name because I've had parser errors with variables named "list" before
List<String> symbol = new List<String>{'*', '°'};
List<String> result= new List<String>{};
for(String s : letters){
    for (String i : symbol){
        result.add(s + i);
    }         
}
```

Comment: the third list is empty list i have wrong to digit before to post. I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate two lists, and get a result of `[a, b, c, *, °]`, there is an addAll() method that you could use:

```
list<String> letters = new list<String>{'a','b','c'};
list<String> symbols = new list<String>{'*', '°'};
letters.addAll(symbols);
list<String> result = letters;
system.debug(result);
```